# How to write a JFIF file?

Tags: jpeg

I'm developing a C++ project, in which I have to compress bitmap data in JPEG format, and write as output a .jpg file that could be opened by a normal image viewer.
I cannot use any kind of libraries.

All the JPEG compression is done, the only thing I'm missing is how to write the stuff in the file correctly.

I already looked into the JFIF format file specification, and googled a lot, but can't figure out how to do it.

More in detail, I should have all the headers put correctly in the file, what I really miss is, after I have the 3 color components ready to be written, how can I do that? (in which order to write the components, how to handle subsampled components (is there other stuff?))

EDIT:

Link to a sample output image (starting from a random generated 8x8 RGB bitmap).

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/46024798/out.jpg

The headers of the image (should) specify that this is a JPEG 8x8px with 3 color components, subsampling 4:4:4.

More in detail, what I did is:

- Generate 3 random 8x8 blocks, with values in range [0..255]
- Subtract 128 to all the elements (now in range [-128..127])
- Apply the Discrete Cosene Transormation to the 3 blocks
- Quantize the result
- Put the results of quantization in zig-zag order
- Look up in the Huffman Tables for the values to write in the files (with End Of Block marker and that kind of stuff)

And for the JPEG compression, that should be ok.

Then I write the file:

- First, I write the SOI header, the APP0 marker, the "magic string" JFIF, version, units, density and thumbnail info
- Then the quantization table
- Then the Start Of Frame marker, with image precision, dimensions, number of components, subsampling info, a DC Huffman Table and an AC Huffman Table
- Then the Start Of Scan header (probably where I messed up), in which I point the IDs of the Huffman Tables to use for each component and other stuff for which I don't know exactly the meaning (spectral selection??, successive approximation??)
- Finally, I write the Huffman Encoded values in this order:

  - All the Y block
  - All the Cb block
  - All the Cr block
- And End Of Image

Comment: Eugh, doing JPEG compression by hand without libraries? That doesn't seem especially fun. So, you already have the Huffman-encoded component blocks ready?

Comment: A project like [jpeg-compressor](http://code.google.com/p/jpeg-compressor/) (self-contained, single file C++ JPEG compression library) might be helpful. Also [jpec](https://github.com/Moodstocks/jpec) - lightweight JPEG encoder written in C, could  be helpful too: have a look at the encoder [`open` function](https://github.com/Moodstocks/jpec/blob/master/src/enc.c#L102) which is really easy to read. But be careful, jpec only supports **grayscale images**.

Comment: Post your work so far and I'll tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: @nneonneo not fun at all :( but to answer your question yes, I already have the Huffmann-encoded blocks.

Comment: @user2057940 - In case you misunderstood my earlier comment. Post a sample file that you generated and I can probably tell you where it's going wrong. To answer your question, the color components are written interleaved depending on the subsampling. For 4:4:4, it's Y, Cb, Cr. For 4:2:0 it's Y0, Y1, Y2, Y3, Cb, Cr.

Comment: @BitBank - I edited my question with a link to an image and a more detailed explanation of what I do.

Comment: @deltheil - thank you for the links, I already had a look to jpeg-compressor before but I got lost in it... but jpec seems a lot easier to read and I'm currently looking into it... seems helpful, thank you a lot!

Comment: I looked at your JPEG output. One thing I noticed is that the color subsampling info is not correct in your SOF0 (FFC0) block. If you're subsampling the color components, then the Y is specified as 0x22 and the Cr and Cb are specified as 0x11. You also define only quantization table 0 (FFDB), yet in your SOF0 marker you specify it to use quantization table 1 for the color components. I didn't verify the Huffman table or compressed data, but those need to be fixed before you can proceed.